# why companies prefer java for programming

Tags: java, .net

most of the good companies prefer java as programming language for s/w development than .net. why?

Comment: Subjective I'd say. You may be better asking this on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: [citation needed] where I work they use C for low level and .NET for web dev

Comment: depends on the software, depends on development platform choice, resources - there are lots of different factors.

Comment: This is usually decided by managers, and not by programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why you would choose Java over .net

Java is multi-platform (Mono is not fully there)
Java is an older language, so people assets in the company might only know that, so the best language is always the language you know.

Really other then that, there is no reason to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

Cause it's easily deployed in heterogeneous environment ranging from Linux to Windows to many different electronic devices.

It has many many frameworks that ease the development and they are reliable cause they are mature enough.

There are a good community carrying a huge knowledge about software development in small and especially in large.

No Manual memory management,
Clear object oriented policies applied in language,
Pointers couldn't mess your code, 
and it's a live language that promote every now and then

Comment: You can say the same thing for C, C++, C#, and just about any other popular programming language.

Comment: IMHO I think porting C and C++ cod bases to different hardware architectures is not a minor task. Could you run C and C++ code on Mobile devices? on Micordevices?

Comment: Zinedine: That doesn't seem to be a problem for cross platform C++ libraries like [this one](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) and [this one](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) and [this one](http://www.gtk.org/). And yes, you can in fact write C and C++ code on embedded devices like microcontrollers.

Comment: I'm not a java programmer and i wrote what's on my mind about Java and .Net, however reading this article my be helpful to everyone about technical debates. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/24/about-technical-debates-both-in-general-and-regarding-asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-in-particular.aspx

Answer (score 1):

java is stable and not restrict in windows, also there many opensource firworks, but also it diffcult to use. I think for small and middle project, .net is the better one. of course how identify the project is the key issue.
the answer why, I think the ture is that they are also many good companies prefer .net, all it depend on the CIO's choose. there even some good companies choose PHP, any language is no problem if it can solve the problem.

Comment: .NET isn't restricted to Windows either.  Check out Mono or DotGNU.

Comment: @cdhowie - neither Mono or DotGNU are fully up to speed with the Microsoft offerings.  Besides, there's alway the possibility that Balmer may wake up one morning and decide to unleash the MS IP lawyers.  (And heaven help you if you are not running on Novell's brand of Linux.)

Comment: @cdhowie, is Mono or DotGNU certified to be fully compatible with .NET?

Comment: @Stephan - Read up on the MS Community Promise, which applies to projects that implement the related specs, not just Novell customers.

Comment: @Andersen: Not certified by any third party, no.  I've had pretty good luck with it myself though.  There is a tool that you can use to analyze compiled assemblies for possible issues, and you of course would have to design apps to be cross-platform in the first place (e.g. don't hardcode "C:" or "\\" as the path separator, but use the members of the Path class).  Compatibility with various APIs varies, of course.